# How to calculate subtotal in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, subtotal

I have a table like this

```
ID      amout1    amount2    amount3
 1       10        0           3    
 1       20        1           1
 2       5         2           2     
 2       0         3          11
```

I want to calculate subtotal for each column

```
ID      amout1    amount2    amount3
 1       10        0           3    
 1       20        1           1
sub      30        1           4
 2       5         2           2     
 2       0         3          11
sub      5         5          13
```

Tried to use group by rollup and grouping sets. But always get some duplicate or null value.

Answer (score 3):

One way is doing the subtotal in another query like this:

```
WITH sample(id, amount1, amount2, amount3) AS (
    VALUES 
        (1, 10, 0, 3),
        (1, 20, 1, 1),
        (2, 5, 2, 2),
        (2, 0, 3, 11)       
)
SELECT *, false AS is_subtotal FROM sample
UNION ALL
SELECT id, sum(amount1), sum(amount2), sum(amount3), true FROM sample GROUP BY id
ORDER BY 
    id,
    is_subtotal;
```

SQLfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e64a4/1).

Comment: The answer using `GROUPING SETS` is the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=542c9b137946f8b30ff56990560ca24f)

If you have Postgres 9.5 or higher you can use [GROUPING SETS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS)

```
SELECT
    id,
    SUM(amount1),
    SUM(amount2),
    SUM(amount3)
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((id, amount1, amount2, amount3),(id))
ORDER BY id
```

The `GROUPING SETS` feature can be thought of a short version of a `UNION` of single `GROUP BY` operations.

Therefore this query executes two groups over the given tuples. The first group is over all columns, so in this case all records stay unique. After that a `SUM` over `id` will be done. Both results will be appended.